# Does Eldritch Researcher allows for +0 (or lower) metamagic?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, feats, magic, metamagic

The [eldritch researcher](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCampaign/characterBackground/storyFeats.html#eldritch-researcher) story feat states:

> Completion Benefit: The save DCs for any spells you create increase by 1 when you cast them. In addition, when applying metamagic feats to self-created spells, reduce the total level adjustment by 1. You can't reduce metamagic costs to **lower than the spell's original level** in this manner.

Let me be the first to say this wording is confusing.

- Does this reduction apply to each metamagic feat?

Or

- Is it refering to the final adjusted spell level (so it only reduces once)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its the total and final adjustment level, as described by feat:

> when applying **metamagic feats** to self-created spells, reduce the **total level adjustment** by 1.

So if you apply silent spell and still spell to your invisibility, it would become a 4th level spell. The feat reduces this to 3rd level, but will never allow it to be reduced to under 2nd level, even if you have other feats, traits and class abilities that reduces metamagic levels.